# Clarity - Dynamic Datagrid

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I was wondering which possibilities I have, to make the DataGrid component more dynamic.

My use case: I have a DataGrid which I want to use for (1) server-driven pagination and sorting and (2) local sorting / filtering.

While both work fine on theire own, I want to build a component, that wraps the DataGrid and makes the decission (server-driven vs local-pagination/filtering etc) configurable.

My current solutions works fine, but is ugly, because I wrap the row-loop in a `ng-container` and there is a lot of copy and paste because the cells are the same.

Example:

```
...
<ng-container *ngIf="serverDriven">
    <clr-dg-row *ngFor="let item of itemList ? itemList : []"
                [clrDgItem]="item"
                clickable>
        <clr-dg-cell>
            {{ item.name }}
        </clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>
            {{ item.description }}
        </clr-dg-cell>
    </clr-dg-row>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!serverDriven">
    <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let sensor of itemList ? itemList : []"
                [clrDgItem]="item"
                clickable>
        <clr-dg-cell>
            {{ item.name }}
        </clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>
            {{ item.description }}
        </clr-dg-cell>
    </clr-dg-row>
</ng-container>
...
```

I tried several approaches with `ngTemplateOutlet` and `ngComponentOutlet` but couldn't get it working because of the multiple providers the datagrid components (e.g. `clr-dg-row`) depend on.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The combination of "server-driven pagination and sorting" and "local sorting/filtering" should imho not be handled in the view itself but at the data source behind the grid. This template binds to a users$ variable, that can be filled whenever the refresh event of the grid is called. The parameter of the refresh method (ClrDatagridStateInterface) provides you with all information to perform loading, filtering and sorting, and the controller can decide if to handle it locally or not.

```
<clr-datagrid (clrDgRefresh)="refresh($event)" [clrDgLoading]="loading">
  <clr-dg-placeholder>No users found</clr-dg-placeholder>
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'name'">Name</clrdg-column>
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'email'">Email</clrdg-column>

  <clr-dg-row *ngFor="let user of users$">
    <clr-dg-cell>{{ user.name }}</clr-dg-cell>
    <clr-dg-cell>{{ user.email }}</clr-dg-cell>
  </clr-dg-row>

  <clr-dg-footer>
    <clr-dg-pagination #pagination [clrDgPageSize]="10" [clrDgTotalItems]="total">
      <clr-dg-page-size [clrPageSizeOptions]="[10, 25]">Page</clr-dg-page-size>
    </clr-dg-pagination>
  </clr-dg-footer>

</clr-datagrid>
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear was my question, but what I want to archieve was, to use the same component for (a) sever-driven und (b) local rendering / filtering etc. 
Sometimes I have lists that are server driven, sometimes I have lists that are not server-drive. So I tried to re-use the same compent for both use cases.
What seems to be the problem, that the local filtering is only possible with `clrDgItems` while I need `*ngFor` for the server-driven use-case.

Comment: And I think you need the logic for filtering and sorting in your controller and not the view. ;)